# What is "NotImplementedError"

Tags: python, package

I was working with some packages. I need to install "base". But when I install it it says:

NotImplementedError: decoding with 'cp1252' codec failed (NotImplementedError: )

I don't understand the meaning of this. Can anyone please help me?

Comment: "*I need to install "base"*": As in you did `pip install base`?

Answer (score 7):

In user defined base classes, abstract methods should raise this exception when they require derived classes to override the method, or while the class is being developed to indicate that the real implementation still needs to be added.

lets say I have `Base` class and which has `foo` method, this method will raise `NotImplementedError` error if we directly call it on `Base`.

```
class Base:
    @property
    def foo(self):
        raise NotImplementedError("Subclasses should implement this!")
```

`foo` method needs to be implemented in `derived` class